# Xcode6 Universal Storyboards and view sizing

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uistoryboard, xcode6

In Xcode6, every new project has a "universal" Storyboard with views sized at 480x480, where we're supposed to use constraints to layout views that will work on iPhone or iPad.

However, when you create a new .xib file, or a new Storyboard, you are presented with a choice of device, iPhone or iPad. Why is this? If the whole point is universal design, why the device selection prompt that forces you into choosing a size that is not the default 480x480 size of the initial Storyboard?

Is this the intended behavior? If so, how do we proceed after choosing iPhone or iPad to get the new .xib or storyboard into a universal state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 6 supports developing apps for iOS 7 and iOS 8. But in iOS 7 we cannot use unified Storyboard so I think that is the reason why Apple offers options for iPhone or iPad when you create a new Storyboard. (I think it should add one more option for "Universal" too)

To switch your file to universal state, please check the option "Use Size Classes" in the File Inspector field.